# How to show the best network structure and save the best network weights?

Tags: c#, encog, neat

I am going to analyze the data using NEAT(Encog C# version). And then, I would like to confirm the network structure and the network weights when the learning was converged. Although I have been reading the Encog documention, I cannot find the articles and sample code. Would it be possible to tell me how to do this(sample code or the other way).

Comment: Thank you for correcting spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check out the [Pluralsight courses by Abishek Kumar](http://app.pluralsight.com/author/abhishek-kumar)  You can watch the courses by signing up for a free trial.

To "confirm the network weights", I would suggest you start with Kumar's "Introduction to Machine Learning with ENCOG 3".  Start with his examples of "Resilient Propagation" or "Quick Propagation" training algorithms, as these are the easiest to setup (its tricky to set the parameters for many of the other training algorithms).  These algorithms will setup the weights of your network.

To "confirm the network structure", I would recommend Kumar's "Advanced Machine Learning with ENCOG" course which has two sections on network tuning.  I would suggest you only use only one hidden layer and use the "Pruning" techniques described in his tutorial (or downloadable code) to choose the number of neurons in the hidden layer.

To decide when the "learning has converged", I would recommend you follow his examples (or download his example code) and use the StopTrainingStrategy (so you automatically stop training when the global error starts increasing) and EarlyStoppingStrategy (so you automatically stop training when the Cross Validation error starts increasing).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll check it out !